# bootstrap-datepicker from/to range by month

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I'm using the https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

My form is consisting of a From Date and a To Date input (#fromdate/#todate).

The minViewMode is set to months for both.

Once a From Date is selected, the user should be able to select ONLY from the #fromdate value PLUS one month.

Ie. if user selects March in From Date, only April and forwards should be selectable in the To Date .datepicker.

Disabling months prior to #fromdate for #todate is handled like so:

```
$("#fromdate").datepicker({
minViewMode: 1
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $("#todate").datepicker('setStartDate',ev.date);
});
```

I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't seem to get a grip on "adding" 1 month to the setStartDate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `minDate`:

```
$("#fromdate").datepicker({
    minViewMode: 1
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $("#todate").datepicker("option", "minDate",ev.date.setMonth(ev.date.getMonth() + 1));
});
```

Comment: minDate is from the jQuery datepicker. The bootstrap equivalent would be startDate. 
I've been trying something along those lines - made a small fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mnorup/c3u9f2m5/

Here you can see the desired effect - except that the #fromdate value is still selectable.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I was on the right path, final solution:

 `$("#fromdate").datepicker({
  minViewMode: 1
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
   startDate: ev.date.setMonth(ev.date.getMonth() + 1),
   $("#todate").datepicker('setStartDate',ev.date);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `endDate` for user.

> The latest date that may be selected; all later dates will be
>   disabled.

Check docs for `bootstrap-datepicker` http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#enddate

Comment: It should be startDate that is relevant for the #todate, not endDate in this case :)

Comment: @MNorup, you get `#fromDate` that user select, after this you init `#toDate` datepicker and set `endDate`

Comment: I'm not sure how that logic would apply - can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I made a more complete solution:

```
$("#eventEndDate").datepicker({
        minViewMode: 1
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        endtDate: ev.date.setMonth(ev.date.getMonth() - 1), $("#eventStartDate").datepicker('setEndDate', ev.date);
    });

    $("#eventStartDate").datepicker({
        minViewMode: 1
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        startDate: ev.date.setMonth(ev.date.getMonth() + 1), $("#eventEndDate").datepicker('setStartDate', ev.date);
    });
```